# how to retrieve Array of integers using List Collection

Tags: c#, generics

In my snippet , I have created int[] array and put it in the List collection , But when I try to fetch my values using Enumerator , I got some unacquainted output that was unexpected.

Here is my small Code :-

```
 int[] i = new int[4];

    for (int p = 0; p <= i.Length - 1; p++)
                 i[p] = p;

    List<int[]> l = new List<int[]>();

    l.Add(i);

    IEnumerator IE = l.GetEnumerator();

    while(IE.MoveNext())
        Console.WriteLine(IE.Current);
```

output is :-

> System.Int32[]

I want to print my int array values . so Please recorrect my code and explain to me what mistake I did in the code

Comment: You're getting the enumerator of the `List<int[]>`, not of the `int[]` inside it. Calling `ToString` on an `int[]` results in what you see in the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print comma separated values of your  array, you can use this code

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", IE.Current))
```